# IIS SQL Server configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012

I have a C# ASP.net project which was developed using Visual studio for web 2013 and SQL Server express 2012.

I used a database connection line as follows:

```
SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MYDB;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=true");
        objConnection.Open();
```

This worked fine when in developer mode in Visual Studio - but now I have deployed to IIS which runs under user `IIS_IUSRS(Andy-PC\IIS_IUSRS)`.

When I visit my pages they then throw the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot open database "MYDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MYDB'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "MYDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MYDB'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MYDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MYDB'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6749670
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClien
```

Its pretty self explanatory - my connection string with integrated security=true is not successfully working as the current logged in user is not IIS_IUSRS.

Can somebody please help to show what I should alter the connection string to in order to create the connection when connecting as this new IIS user?

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication in your connection string?

Comment: Isn't `Data Source=.\\MYDB` mean you hitting local server? So, if you deployed it somewhere else, you probably need to replace dot (`.`) with real server name or IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the user that your application pool is running as.

Go to Advance Setting for the Application Pool and change the Identity to a user that can access your sql server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use that connection string, just grant permissions to `IIS APPPOOL\MYDB` in your SQL server and database.

Answer (score 1):

Using an explicit account for the site may make managing security easier in the long run, e.g. placing a connection string in the `Web.config` file for your ASP .NET project like:

```
<add name="SiteDB"
  connectionString="Data Source=HostName\SQLServerInstance; Initial Catalog=MyDB; User Id=MyFirstWebsite; Password=secret"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Then using `ConfigurationManager` to get the connection string.

When there are several sites on the server this will make it clear which database this site should be using and, if several of the sites share the database, you can have them use different credentials so that they can have different access restrictions.